# Unable to access Facebook account

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

Can't use Facebook anymore. When I login it says:

> "Review recent posts and likes Hi Name, it looks like your account was sending out spam. We would like to help you secure your account. Please help us by making sure all recent likes and posts were made by you."[image: That's the problem i am facing any help please]

Answer (score -2):

I tried so many times to report this to facebook but not having any response. very very annoying this is really hampering me. I have lots of professional and educational connectivity through that account.

Anyone know how to get back to FB again ?